# Copy the content of a document file and append it into another keeping it formatted C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to copy the content of a document file to another keeping it formatted. I found a way to copy the whole document to a new one using `File.Copy(file, newFile, true);` but I need to append the content to another existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick code sample that should get you on your way:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var wdApp = new Word.Application();
var documents = wdApp.Documents;
var doc = documents.Open(newFile);
doc.Content.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
doc.Content.InsertFile(file);
```